# Union tables based on row count

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I union tables based on row count

For instance, assume I have 10 tables and have to select the top 10 rows as below

> 1. If table1 has 10 rows then return 10 rows.
> 2. If table1 has 5 rows then union table2 and return the top 10 rows(if row count>10 then don't union table3 and etc)
> 3. If table1 has 3 rows and table2 has 2 rows then union with table 3 and return the top 10 rows and so on.

My current SQL query is below, but this one union all table and returns top 10 which is not performant (I think).

```
SELECT TOP 10  NAME FROM(
SELECT TOP 10 NAME FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME LIKE '%abc%'
UNION
SELECT TOP 10 NAME FROM TABLE2 WHERE NAME LIKE '%abc%'
UNION
..
..
SELECT TOP 10 NAME FROM TABLE10 WHERE NAME LIKE '%abc%'
) AS RESULT
```

Comment: `f table1 has 5 rows then union table2 and return the top 10 rows` Then return the top 10 rows from what table ? 5 of table1 and the rest of table2 ? or 10 of table2 ? Or something else ? You need to explain better what you need, maybe with some sample data

Comment: A `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a sign of a flaw as well.

Comment: If you are concerned about the performance, You can use `UNION ALL` over `UNION`. As `UNION` gives out the distinct rows it is slow for large tables

Comment: @GuidoG, union table1 with table2 and select top 10. if row count of (table1 union table 2) is less then 10 then union table3

Comment: "which is not performant (I think)"   Did you try it? and what was the result of your try ?

Comment: @Luuk, it is obvious, isn't it? I need only the first 10 rows so if the union of two tables gives 10 rows then I don't want to union another table.

Comment: Enable [Actual Execution Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver16), and compare the results of your attempts.  When executing more the one queries at once, SSMS will display `Query cost (relative to batch): x%`, which is helpful to see which of  queries has best most performance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you maybe need something like this ?

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A) = 3 
begin
select * from A
end
else
select * from A
Union all
select * from B
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e5eec2e6db3c32031ce295913ab3758e)

Comment: will this work if I have 100 tables

Comment: Try it out and let us know ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add an extra column to each table specifying its position, then order by that column and take the top 10 rows

```sql
SELECT TOP (10)
  NAME
FROM (
    SELECT NAME, 1 AS Ordering
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE NAME LIKE '%abc%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NAME, 2
    FROM TABLE2
    WHERE NAME LIKE '%abc%'
    UNION ALL
..
..
    SELECT NAME, 10
    FROM TABLE10
    WHERE NAME LIKE '%abc%'
) AS RESULT
ORDER BY
  Ordering;
```